# Ajuda com consulta SQL com COUNT em multiplas linhas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, count

Olá, estou fazendo a seguinte consulta

```
SELECT p.id, c.nome, v.titulo, count(v.titulo)
FROM passageiros   AS p
LEFT JOIN clientes AS c ON c.id = p.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN viagens  AS v ON v.id = p.id_viagem
GROUP BY v.titulo;
```

E ela esta me retornando o seguinte resultado:

> ```
> id| nome       | titulo                  |  count(v.titulo)
> 1 | 'bruno'    | 'gramado'               |  5
> 6 | 'alea vang'| 'gramado - mundo magico'|  5
> 11| 'bruno'    | 'beto carrero'          |  3
> 14| 'bruno'    | 'caminhos rurais'       |  6
> ```

Porém o que eu gostaria é que ela retornasse a lista de cada um dos nomes de cada titulo junto com o *count* total daquele titulo:

> ```
> id| nome               | titulo                   | count(v.titulo)
> 1 | 'bruno'            | 'gramado'                | 5
> 2 | 'tamires'          | 'gramado'                | 5
> 3 | 'christen wiggins' | 'gramado'                | 5
> 4 | 'justine howard'   | 'gramado'                | 5
> 5 | 'anika hammond'    | 'gramado'                | 5
> 6 | 'alea vang'        | 'gramado - mundo magico' | 5
> 7 | 'fredericka jensen'| 'gramado - mundo magico' | 5
> 8 | 'alexa duncan'     | 'gramado - mundo magico' | 5
> 9 | 'lynn mclean'      | 'gramado - mundo magico' | 5
> 10| 'allegra cantrell' | 'gramado - mundo magico' | 5
> 11| 'bruno'            | 'beto carrero'           | 3 
> 12| 'tamires'          | 'beto carrero'           | 3
> 13| 'christen wiggins' | 'beto carrero'           | 3
> 14| 'bruno'            | 'caminhos rurais'        | 6
> 15| 'tamires'          | 'caminhos rurais'        | 6
> 16| 'christen wiggins' | 'caminhos rurais'        | 6
> 17| 'alexa duncan'     | 'caminhos rurais'        | 6
> 18| 'lynn mclean'      | 'caminhos rurais'        | 6
> 19| 'allegra cantrell' | 'caminhos rurais'        | 6
> ```

EDIT:
Ao fazer a consulta utilizando `GROUP BY v.titulo, p.id;` eu tenho o retorno da lista completa dos nomes, porém o `count` retorna apenas `1` em todos as linhas.
Tentei criar o `count` dentro de uma subquery, mas por ele retornar vários resultados, a pesquisa não teve sucesso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais simples de fazer isso é com uma *subconsulta*; você cria um *select* pra retornar o total de registros da viagem da linha pesquisada:

```
SELECT p.id, c.nome, v.titulo, (select count(*) from passageiros p2 where p2.id_viagem = p.id_viagem) as total
FROM passageiros AS p
LEFT JOIN clientes AS c ON c.id = p.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN viagens AS v ON v.id = p.id_viagem
```

Dá uma olhada [nesse fiddle](https://rextester.com/KTZ57332) que tá funcionando como deseja.

Comment: Estava quase no caminho certo, em meus testes acabei fazendo uma consulta parecida com esta, porém estava fazendo a comparação errada no `where`, muito obrigado.

Comment: massa, mete bronca =]

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução, como indicou na pergunta, passa por calcular o total de passageiros para cada viagem numa subquery. Fica aqui um exemplo que deve devolver o resultado esperado.

```
SELECT p.id, c.nome, v.titulo, t.num_total_passageiros
  FROM passageiros p
  LEFT JOIN clientes c 
    ON c.id = p.id_cliente
  LEFT JOIN viagens v
    ON v.id = p.id_viagem
  LEFT JOIN 
 (  
    SELECT ip.id_viagem, COUNT(DISTINCT ip.id) as num_total_passageiros
      FROM viagens iv
     GROUP BY ip.id_viagem     
 ) t
   ON t.id_viagem = v.id
ORDER BY p.id
```

Comment: Gostaria de agradecer a disposição, foi de muita ajuda e também retornou o resultado esperado, porém escolhi a outra solução pela simplicidade dela, mas quero deixar registrado que esta também funcionou perfeitamente bem, muito obrigado.

Comment: @bruno101. Não tem que agradecer!

Answer (score 0):

Opa. Pelo que consegui entender de sua dúvida, queres que a coluna "nome" não se repita na sua consulta. Portanto, o que quer seria basicamente saber quantas vezes que o cliente 'x' fez a viagen 'y', isso?
Nesse caso, bastaria adicionar ao seu group by o nome do cliente. Segue exemplo:

```
SELECT p.id, c.nome, v.titulo, count(v.titulo)
FROM passageiros   AS p
LEFT JOIN clientes AS c ON c.id = p.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN viagens  AS v ON v.id = p.id_viagem
GROUP BY c.nome, v.titulo;
```

Espero ter ajudado! Caso não seja isto, espero que outros consigam sanar sua dúvida!
Valeu!

Comment: Com esta consulta ele retorna todos os nomes, porém o `count` fica com `1`, eu gostaria que ele retornasse o  `count` correto para cada titulo de lugar em cada registro, tentei fazer com uma `subquery`, porém sem sucesso, visto que para alguns resultados ele retorna 5, outros 3, outros ainda retorna 6 (como na primeira tabela de exemplo). Mas muito obrigado por tentar ajudar.